# Mongodb mongoose storing empty documents on my database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have wasted 1 day so far and can't find a solution for this problem,

i setup a server with express everything working fine, i can log into server.js username, email and password i'm receiving from react registration page, but when i add it to a collection with mongoose all it shows is ID no username, email or password

[picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FGei.png)

here is the code,

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./models/User");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/storedUsers");

app.post("/api/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, username } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const newUser = await User.create({
      email,
      password,
      username,
    });`enter code here`
    newUser.save();
    res.json({ status: "user created" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.json({ status: "error", error: "Duplicate email" });
  }
});
```

this is the log im getting:

```
 

    {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: '{"email":"test1@mail.com","password":"test1","username":"test1"}'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you handle the data insertion?

Comment: Hi, i posted the code

Comment: Can you post the result of the `console.log(req.body);` line?

Comment: How is the User model defined?